# How to play video in Rio play 2.0

Tags: .net

- Hello can any buddy help me how do i play video lectures in Rio player i am facing issue,while playing lecture it showing that Rio player application has stopeed working.Please help me to out this.
  Thanks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try reinstalling app from [RecordShield.Net](https://recordshield.net/downloads)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.